# Integrating Payment Gateway in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, payment-gateway

integration payment gateway in asp.net webform based website. sample code documentation examples are in php only.

I am not sure how to go forward as documentation doesnt seem to be of much help

https://telr.com/support/knowledge-base/hosted-payment-page-integration-guide/

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="PaymentProcess.aspx.cs" Inherits="PaymentProcess" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
  #telr {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    frameborder: 0;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
       <p> Enter You Credit Card Details Here</p>
<p><iframe id= " telr " src= " [url obtained from create order] " ></iframe></p>
<div>

 </div>

    </form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help or pointer is appreciated

UPDATE:

I am trying to using HTTPClient for same but i am not sure if i am doing it wring

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        TelrObj obj = new TelrObj();

        obj.ivp_method = "create";
        obj.ivp_store = 12345;
        obj.ivp_cart = "cardid1234";
        obj.ivp_test = 1;
        obj.return_auth = "xxxx-xxxx-xxx";
        obj.return_can = "";
        obj.return_decl = "";
        obj.ivp_amount = 10;
        obj.bill_fname = "David";
        obj.ivp_currency = "USD";

        var str = "{ 'method':'create', 'order':{  'ref':'OrderRef', 'cartid':'cardid1234', 'test':1,'amount':10,'currency':'USD', 'url':'https://secure.telr.com/gateway/process.html?o=OrderRef'  }";


        var response = client.PostAsync("https://secure.telr.com/gateway/order.json",
            new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(str).ToString(),
                Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
                .Result;

        Response.Write(response);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            dynamic content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(
                response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
                .Result);

            // Access variables from the returned JSON object
            var appHref = content.links.applications.href;
        }
    }


}
```

**RESPONSE**

`StatusCode: 417, ReasonPhrase: 'Expectation Failed', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers: { Connection: close Date: Tue, 17 Jan 2017 10:52:30 GMT Server: Apache Content-Length: 364 Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 }`

I have changed `return_auth` & `ivp_store` as i cant share it. Any pointer to do it right would be of great help.

I am confused with there documentation so to do it right way. They dont seem to have any .net example on their website rather they have PHP Plugins which i don't understand.

I found another example for wooCommerce plugin which is in PHP

```
<?php


if (!defined('ABSPATH')) { exit; } // Exit if accessed directly
if (!defined('WP_CONTENT_URL')) { define('WP_CONTENT_URL', get_option('siteurl').'/wp-content'); }
if (!defined('WP_PLUGIN_URL')) { define('WP_PLUGIN_URL', WP_CONTENT_URL.'/plugins'); }
if (!defined('WP_CONTENT_DIR')) { define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', ABSPATH.'wp-content'); }
if (!defined('WP_PLUGIN_DIR')) { define('WP_PLUGIN_DIR', WP_CONTENT_DIR.'/plugins'); }

function telr_init() {
    /**
    * __construct function.
    *
    * @access public
    * @return void
    */
    class WC_Gateway_Telr extends WC_Payment_Gateway {

        public function __construct() {
            global $woocommerce;

            $this->min_wc_ver="2.3.8";
            $this->id = 'telr';
            $this->has_fields = false;  // No additional fields in checkout page
            $this->method_title = __('Telr', 'woocommerce');
            $this->method_description = __('Telr Checkout', 'telr-for-woocommerce');
            $this->order_button_text = __( 'Proceed to Telr', 'telr-for-woocommerce' );
            $this->woocom_ver = $woocommerce->version;

            // Load the settings.
            $this->init_form_fields();  // Config page fields
            $this->init_settings();

            if ($this->can_init()) {
                $preload='<iframe style="width:1px;height:1px;visibility:hidden;display:none;" src="https://secure.telrcdn.com/preload.html"></iframe>';
                $this->enabled          = $this->get_config_option('enabled');
                $this->title            = $this->get_config_option('title');
                $this->description      = $this->get_config_option('description').$preload;
                $this->store_id         = $this->get_config_option('store_id');
                $this->store_secret     = $this->get_config_option('store_secret');
                $this->testmode         = $this->get_config_option('testmode');
                $this->debug            = $this->get_config_option('debug');
                $this->order_status     = $this->get_config_option('order_status');
                $this->cart_desc        = $this->get_config_option('cart_desc');
                $this->form_submission_method   = true;
                $this->api_endpoint = 'https://secure.telr.com/gateway/order.json';

                // Actions
                add_action('woocommerce_update_options_payment_gateways_'.$this->id, array($this, 'process_admin_options'));
                add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', array($this, 'update_order_status'));

            } else {
                $this->enabled = false;
            }

        }

        private function can_init() {
            if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.5.0') < 0) {
                return false;
            }
            if (!function_exists('curl_version')) { return false; }
            if (!function_exists('curl_init')) { return false; }
            if (version_compare($this->woocom_ver,$this->min_wc_ver) < 0) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }


        public function update_order_status($order_id) {
            global $woocommerce;

            $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
            $order_check = $this->check_order($order_id);

            if($order_check) {
                $new_status = $this->sorder_status;
                if (empty($new_status)) { $new_status="completed"; }
                $order->update_status($new_status);
            }
        }


        /**
        * Process the payment and return the result.
        *
        * @access public
        * @return array
        */
        function process_payment($order_id) {
            $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
            $result = $this->generate_request($order);
            $telr_ref = trim($result['order']['ref']);
            $telr_url= trim($result['order']['url']);

            if (empty($telr_ref) || empty($telr_url)) {
                wc_add_notice('Payment API Failure, Please try again.', 'error');
            } else {
                update_post_meta( $order_id, '_telr_ref', $telr_ref);
            }

            return array(
                'result'    => 'success',
                'redirect'  => $telr_url,
            );

        }

        public function generate_request($order) {
            global $woocommerce;

            $order_id = $order->id;

            $cart_id = $order_id."_".uniqid();
            $cart_desc=trim($this->cart_desc);
            if (empty($cart_desc)) { $cart_desc='Order {order_id}'; }
            $cart_desc = preg_replace('/{order_id}/i',$order_id,$cart_desc);

            $test_mode = ($this->testmode == 'yes') ? 1 : 0;
            $return_url = 'auto:'.add_query_arg('utm_nooverride','1',$this->get_return_url($order));
            $cancel_url = 'auto:'.$order->get_cancel_order_url();

            $data = array(
                'ivp_method'    => "create",
                'ivp_source'    => 'WooCommerce '.$woocommerce->version,
                'ivp_store' => $this->store_id ,
                'ivp_authkey'   => $this->store_secret,
                'ivp_cart'  => $cart_id,
                'ivp_test'  => $test_mode,
                'ivp_amount'    => $order->order_total,
                'ivp_currency'  => get_woocommerce_currency(),
                'ivp_desc'  => $cart_desc,
                'return_auth'   => $return_url,
                'return_can'    => $cancel_url,
                'return_decl'   => $cancel_url,
                'bill_fname'    => $order->billing_first_name,
                'bill_sname'    => $order->billing_last_name,
                'bill_addr1'    => $order->billing_address_1,
                'bill_addr2'    => $order->billing_address_2,
                'bill_city' => $order->billing_city,
                'bill_region'   => $order->billing_state,
                'bill_zip'  => $order->billing_postcode,
                'bill_country'  => $order->billing_country,
                'bill_email'    => $order->billing_email,
                );

            if (is_ssl() && is_user_logged_in()) {
                $data['bill_custref'] = get_current_user_id();
            }

            $response = $this->api_request($data);
            return $response;
        }

        public function check_order($order_id) {
            global $woocommerce;

            $order_ref = get_post_meta($order_id, '_telr_ref', true);

            $data = array(
                'ivp_method'    => "check",
                'ivp_store' => $this->store_id ,
                'order_ref' => $order_ref,
                'ivp_authkey'   => $this->store_secret,
                );

            $response = $this->api_request($data);

            $order_status_arr = array(2,3);
            $transaction_status_arr = array('A', 'H');

            if (array_key_exists("order", $response)) {
                $order_status = $response['order']['status']['code'];
                $transaction_status = $response['order']['transaction']['status'];
                if ( in_array($order_status, $order_status_arr) && in_array($transaction_status, $transaction_status_arr)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        public function api_request($data) {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->api_endpoint);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:'));
            $results = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            $results = json_decode($results,true);
            return $results;
        }


        /* ------------------------------ Admin setting page ------------------------------------------------ */

        public function get_config_option($key) {
            return $this->get_option($key);
        }

        public function admin_options() {
            if ($this->can_init()) {
                $this->show_admin_options();
            } else {
                $this->not_available();
            }
        }

        public function not_available() {
            ?>
            <div class="inline error"><p><strong><?php _e( 'Gateway Disabled', 'woocommerce' ); ?></strong>: <?php _e( sprintf('Requires WooCommerce %s or later, PHP 5.5 or later, and PHP cURL',$this->min_wc_ver), 'woocommerce' ); ?></p></div>
            <?php
        }

        public function show_admin_options() {
            // Admin Panel Options
            $configured = true;
            if ((empty($this->store_id)) || (empty($this->store_secret))) { $configured=false; }

            ?>
            <h3><?php _e('Telr', 'woocommerce'); ?></h3>
            <?php if (!$configured) : ?>
                <div id="wc_get_started">
                <span class="main"><?php _e('Telr Hosted Payment Page', 'woocommerce'); ?></span>
                <span><a href="https://www.telr.com/" target="_blank">Telr</a> <?php _e('are a PCI DSS Level 1 certified payment gateway. We guarantee that we will handle the storage, processing and transmission of your customer\'s cardholder data in a manner which meets or exceeds the highest standards in the industry.', 'woocommerce'); ?></span>
                <span><br><b>NOTE: </b> You must enter your store ID and authentication key</span>
                </div>
            <?php else : ?>
                <p><?php _e('Telr Hosted Payment Page', 'woocommerce'); ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <table class="form-table">
            <?php $this->generate_settings_html(); ?>
            </table><!--/.form-table-->
            <?php
        }

        // Admin settings fields
        function init_form_fields() {
            // Initialise Gateway Settings Form Fields
            $this->form_fields = array(
                'enabled' => array(
                    'title'     => __('Enable/Disable', 'woocommerce'),
                    'type'      => 'checkbox',
                    'label'     => __('Enable Telr', 'woocommerce'),
                    'default'   => 'yes'
                ),
                'title' => array(
                    'title'     => __('Title', 'woocommerce'),
                    'type'      => 'text',
                    'description'   => __('This controls the title which the user sees during checkout.', 'woocommerce'),
                    'default'   => __('Credit/Debit card', 'woocommerce'),
                    'desc_tip'  => true,
                ),
                'description' => array(
                    'title'     => __('Description', 'woocommerce'),
                    'type'      => 'textarea',
                    'description'   => __('This controls the description which the user sees during checkout.', 'woocommerce'),
                    'default'   => __('Pay using a credit or debit card via Telr Secure Payments', 'woocommerce'),
                    'desc_tip'  => true,
                ),
                'cart_desc' => array(
                    'title'     => __('Transaction description', 'woocommerce'),
                    'type'      => 'text',
                    'description'   => __('This controls the transaction description shown within the hosted payment page.', 'woocommerce'),
                    'default'   => __('Your order from StoreName', 'woocommerce'),
                    'desc_tip'  => true,
                ),
                'store_id' => array(
                    'title'     => __('Store ID', 'woocommerce'),
                    'type'      => 'text',
                    'description'   => __('Enter your Telr Store ID.', 'woocommerce'),
                    'default'   => '',
                    'desc_tip'  => true,
                    'placeholder'   => '[StoreID]'
                ),
                'store_secret' => array(
                    'title'     => __('Authentication Key', 'woocommerce'),
                    'type'      => 'text',
                    'description'   => __('This value must match the value configured in the hosted payment page V2 settings', 'woocommerce'),
                    'default'   => '',
                    'desc_tip'  => true,
                    'placeholder'   => '[Authentication Key]'
                ),
                'testmode' => array(
                    'title'     => __('Test Mode', 'woocommerce'),
                    'type'      => 'checkbox',
                    'label'     => __('Generate transactions in test mode', 'woocommerce'),
                    'default'   => 'yes',
                    'description'   => __('Use this whilst testing your integration. You must disable test mode when you are ready to take live transactions')
                ),
                'order_status' => array(
                    'title'     => __('Order Status', 'woocommerce'),
                    'type'      => 'select',
                    'label'     => __('Order status for authorised payments', 'woocommerce'),
                    'default'   => 'processing',
                    'description'   => __('Set the WooCommerce order status that will be used for authorised transations', 'woocommerce'),
                    'options'   => array(
                        'processing'    => __( 'Processing', 'woocommerce' ),
                        'completed' => __( 'Completed', 'woocommerce' )
                    )
                )
            );
        }


    }
}



if(!function_exists('telr_list_network_plugins')) {
    function telr_list_network_plugins() {
        if (!is_multisite()) {
            return false;
        $sitewide_plugins = array_keys((array) get_site_option('active_sitewide_plugins'));
        }
        if (!is_array($sitewide_plugins)) {
            return false;
        }
        return $sitewide_plugins;
    }
}

function add_telr_gateway($methods) {
    $methods[] = 'WC_Gateway_Telr';
    return $methods;
}

// Add plugin to wordpress/woocommerce
if ((in_array('woocommerce/woocommerce.php', (array)get_option('active_plugins'))) || (in_array('woocommerce/woocommerce.php', (array)telr_list_network_plugins()))) {
    add_action('plugins_loaded', 'telr_init', 0);
    add_filter('woocommerce_payment_gateways', 'add_telr_gateway');
}
?>
```

Comment: Example show a simple HTTP request using cURL, what exactly you don't know?

Comment: @komo This is the example shown in teh documentation but i need same working in asp.net webform based website. I am trying to do it with HTTPClient but i get error 417 always.

Comment: @komo, I have updated question

Comment: Basically you haven't gone thru the documentation properly and tried to jump into the code without understanding documentation properly. Its the logic which will help you not the the technology.

Comment: JsonConvert.SerializeObject(str) should be JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj) that will serialize the object and create required JSON for the order.json API. The value you have in  "str" is something which you will recieve from the API.

Comment: I used `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj)` first it also gives error so i create another json using string `str`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I use Postman and send a following request to the `https://secure.telr.com/gateway/order.json` I'm getting `HTTP 200`:

```
POST /gateway/order.json HTTP/1.1
Host: secure.telr.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 570a44c1-9c4e-58b2-5d4d-fdd352272235

ivp_method=create&ivp_store=12345&ivp_authkey=12345&ivp_cart=12345&ivp_test=1&ivp_amount=100.00&ivp_currency=AED&ivp_desc=Description&return_auth=https%3A%2F%2Fdomain.com%2Freturn.html&return_can=https%3A%2F%2Fdomain.com%2Freturn.html&return_decl=https%3A%2F%2Fdomain.com%2Freturn.html
```

So I guess you're building your request in a wrong way(especially `Content-Type` which should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, not `application/json`).

I cannot test it more since I don't `ivp_store` parameter, thus following response appears:

```
{
  "method": "create",
  "trace": "4001/18544/587dfa99",
  "error": {
    "message": "E04:Invalid store ID"
  }
}
```

EDIT:

Here's working example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://secure.telr.com/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;

        var result = client.PostAsync("gateway/order.json",
            new FormUrlEncodedContent(new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ivp_method", "create"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ivp_store", "12345"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ivp_authkey", "12345"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ivp_cart", "12345"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ivp_desc", "Desc"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ivp_test", "1"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ivp_amount", "100.00"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ivp_currency", "AED"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("return_auth", "https://wwww.google.pl"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("return_can", "https://wwww.google.pl"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("return_decl", "https://wwww.google.pl"),
            })).Result;

        Console.WriteLine(result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Note following line:

`client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;`

which is required for this server. If you do not include this line and run my code, you will get following response:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>417 Expectation Failed</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Expectation Failed</h1>
<p>The expectation given in the Expect request-header
field could not be met by this server.
The client sent<pre>
    Expect: 100-continue
</pre>
</p><p>Only the 100-continue expectation is supported.</p>
</body></html>
```

`HttpClient` by default sends a `Expect: 100-continue` header, which clearly messes with a server you're trying to connect.

Comment: It's just a Chrome extension. I guess I can get the same result using `HttpClient` from `.NET`.

Comment: Can you please share the piece of C# code so that i can test also. I tried on POstman also i am not able to make it work i keep getting Bad Request

Comment: @Learning - posted a solution for your problem.

Comment: Appreciate that i will try it

Comment: Surelly i will, I am jus facing problem with Result set as i have to pass multiple datypes in KeyValuePair as i frame which is retured show as blank i am sure that is due to single datatype i am passing. I am using ` `var response = client.PostAsync("https://secure.telr.com/gateway/order.json",
                new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj).ToString(),
                    Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
                    .Result;`

Comment: @Learning You cannot use `StringContent` and `application/json` - it has to be `FormUrlEncodedContent`.

Comment: I have marked your question as correct, Appreciate you solution